# pushing rails 4 app to heroku epic fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Pushing this rails 4 app to heroku. Any help is appreciated. App is copied straight from Lynda.com Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training Exercise files zip. I read other posts and removed the gemfile.lock then ran bundle install but it didn't many any difference. There shouldn't be a problem? Thanks anyway

```
ggeorgiev@ubuntu:~/projects/simple_cms_4$ git push heroku master
Initializing repository, done.
Counting objects: 173, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (161/161), done.
Writing objects: 100% (173/173), 47.04 KiB, done.
Total 173 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.5.2
   New app detected loading default bundler cache
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
   Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
   Using rake (10.1.0)
   Using minitest (4.7.5)
   Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
   Using builder (3.1.4)
   Using erubis (2.7.0)
   Using rack (1.5.2)
   Installing multi_json (1.7.7)
   Using polyglot (0.3.3)
   Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
   Installing mime-types (1.23)
   Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
   Using hike (1.2.3)
   Using json (1.8.0)
   Installing arel (4.0.0)
   Using bundler (1.5.2)
   Using thor (0.18.1)
   Using tilt (1.4.1)
   Using rack-test (0.6.2)
   Installing treetop (1.4.14)
   Using rdoc (3.12.2)
   Using sprockets (2.10.0)
   Using mail (2.5.4)
   Using sdoc (0.3.20)
   Installing i18n (0.6.4)
   Installing atomic (1.1.10)
   Installing thread_safe (0.1.2)
   Installing activesupport (4.0.0)
   Installing activemodel (4.0.0)
   Installing actionpack (4.0.0)
   Installing activerecord (4.0.0)
   Installing actionmailer (4.0.0)
   Installing railties (4.0.0)
   Installing sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
   Installing acts_as_list (0.3.0)
   Installing rails (4.0.0)
   Installing mysql2 (0.3.13)
   Your bundle is complete!
   Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
   It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
   Bundle completed (17.99s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   I, [2014-01-22T13:17:44.812043 #1278]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/public/assets/footer_gradient-4f04310658a469a35a8014a13e9e1fff.png
   I, [2014-01-22T13:17:44.816570 #1278]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/public/assets/plus_sign-d0a969825c4cf5d10c388d8449c717c0.png
   rake aborted!
   couldn't find file 'jquery'
   (in /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13)
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:106:in `resolve'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:146:in `require_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:217:in `process_require_directive'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:167:in `block in process_directives'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `each'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:165:in `process_directives'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb:99:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /tmp/build_8a07d45d-d10f-448a-9d51-c50b5e9fdd7c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:intense-tor-3783.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:intense-tor-3783.git'
ggeorgiev@ubuntu:~/projects/simple_cms_4$
```

Answer (score 3):

It's trying to compile your assets without access to jQuery. You need to uncomment/add `gem 'jquery-rails'` to your Gemfile. If you haven't already, Heroku also recommends adding `gem 'rails_12factor'`.